Intellij disable inserting space after typing dot on new line
For example I want to type a multi-line code like this
list.stream()
  .filter(...)
  .map(...)

I end with it like
list.stream()
      .filter(...)
          .map(...)

IntelliJ is inserting tab/spaces every time when I press dot on a new line.
GIF:

I have tried also:
Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Chained method calls > Align when multiline
But is not helping. At enter-key(new line) the cursor is aligned with .stream(), but after I type dot, still jump to the right.
Someone has any idea what I can do?
P.S.: I don't remember to have this problem in past and I guess it appeared with the last update. I may be wrong.
Version: 2024.1.2 (ultimate-edition)
